# Error tras actualizar a cordova 6.4.0 en un proyecto con Meteor

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor

Tengo un proyecto que estaba corriendo con cordova 6.3.1 y andaba todo ok.
Despues de agregar phonegap-plugin-push empecé a tener problemas

```
%% Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 6.3.1, failed version requirement: >=6.4.0
%% Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for android                                  
%% Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 6.3.1, failed version requirement: >=6.4.0
%% Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for ios
```

Asi que actualice cordova a 6.4.0 (meteor add cordova:cordova@6.4.0) y ahora estoy teniendo otros problemas.

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:                                           

   While adding plugin cordova@6.4.0 to Cordova project:                        
   Cordova error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "package". Please try       
   adding it again.
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not 
   apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the
   --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)

/Users/diegodedieu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.tjodye++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/runtime/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
  throw error;
  ^
  ExitWithCode:1
```

Como puedo solucionar estos problemas?

Comment: Que versión del plugin instalaste? trata con una version anterior a 1.9.0

Comment: la verdad que no se cual version es, tratare borrarla e instalar una anterior a ver si soluciono.

El tema es que ahora tampoco me dejaba volver a cordova 6.3.1, me seguia tirando el error de cannot find plugin xml.

Trate borrando el /local de /.meteor, con 'meteor reset', con meteor remove-platform, meteor remove cordova:cordova pero siempre termino en el mismo error

Comment: Si la instalaste desde github.com la versión indicada es la 1.9.0 : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/package.json

Comment: El problema puede ser lo que dice ahí `Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "package".` no ha encontrado el archivo plugin.xml, por lo que deberías ver como conseguirlo nuevamente.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo esta librería https://github.com/raix/push concretamente esta version raix:push@=3.0.2

Comment: Te recomiendo que no uses cordoba. Yo hice muchas apps con cordoba/phonegap al principio de empezar a desarrollar y un dia recibo desde los stores que mi versión de cordoba tiene un problema de seguridad. A actualizar todas las apps... Yo lo desaconsejo totalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor lleva una version de Cordova integrada (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/scripts/dev-bundle-tool-package.js#L57), no la puedes actualizar.

Cuando haces `meteor add cordova:cordova@6.4.0` le vuelves loco porque se piensa que estás añadiendo un plugin y por eso te dice que no hay plugin.xml porque Cordova no es un plugin y no tiene un plugin.xml

Por el momento tendrás que usar una versión anterior del plugin (1.8.4) hasta que meteor actualice la cordova-lib a 6.4.0

Comment: Gracias, al final lo pude volver a hacer andar pero con la version 6.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

El mismo mensaje te indica el problema,

> %% Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova:
>   6.3.1, failed version requirement: >=6.4.0 %% Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for android

el plugin versión 1.9.0, requiere como mínimo una version 6.4.0.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md

Comment: Si, por eso es que actualice a 6.4.0 y ahi es donde estoy trancado ahora, en el otro error